# Groovy script for a Jenkins multijob pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a multijob pipeline that triggers several other builds to run. It takes in a couple of choice parameters (PRODUCT and BRANCH) to separate the builds into different groups. The UI was easy to set up and works well.  Now I need to transfer the same functionality onto a Groovy script instead of using the UI.  I have the script below, but it's not working. I'm getting the following error message:
`eCaught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method...`

I'm pretty sure my syntax is way off:

```html
    pipeline {
        parameters {
            choice(
                choices: ['A', 'B'],
                description: 'Select which set of artifacts to trigger',
                name: 'PRODUCT')         
            choice(
                choices: ['develop', 'release'],
                description: 'Select which branch to build the artifacts from',
                name: 'BRANCH')  
        }
        stages {
            stage ('Build') {
                when {
                    expression {
                        env.PRODUCT == 'A' && env.BRANCH == 'release'
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    parallel (
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact1/release'), 
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact2/release'),
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact3/release'),
                    )
                }
                when {
                    expression {
                        env.PRODUCT == 'A' && env.BRANCH == 'develop'
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    parallel (
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact1/develop'), 
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact2/develop'),
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact3/develop'),
                    )
                }
                when {
                    expression {
                        env.PRODUCT == 'B' && env.BRANCH == 'release'
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    parallel (
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact4/release'), 
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact5/release'),
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact6/release'),
                }
                when {
                    expression {
                        env.PRODUCT == 'B' && env.BRANCH == 'develop'
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    parallel (
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact4/develop'), 
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact5/develop'),
                        build (job: '../../Builds/artifact6/develop'),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the steps , run the build in a script segment, it might help

```
script{
                            j1BuildResult = build job: "Compile", propagate: true, wait: true, parameters: [
                                    //booleanParam(name: 'portal', value: env.PORTAL),
                                    string(name: 'BRANCH', value: params.BRANCH),
                                    booleanParam(name: 'portal', value: false),
                                    string(name: 'db', value: params.SCHEME_NAME),
                            ]
}
```